# ESP8266 print DNS address (obtained via DHCP)

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I've set up an ESP8266 (Wemos D1 Mini) to get IP-information via DHCP.
Everything works fine and I can print the information :

Serial.print(WiFi.macAddress());
Serial.print(WiFI.localIP());
Serial.print(WiFi.subnetMask());
Serial.print(WiFi.gateway.IP());

But how do I print the DNS-address ??

I cant find a function for this ???

/Kind regards : Gurra

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html#dnsip

Answer (score 5):

```
Serial.println(WiFi.dnsIP());
```

If you have more than one DNS server you can specify the index:

```
Serial.println(WiFi.dnsIP(1));
```

Comment: Thanks Majenko, i've Googled this question and found answers to ip, netmask, mac & gateway but not DNS, so you saved me hours of extra work by this....So I am very grateful !!

Comment: You're welcome. You can find all the functions in the ESP8266WiFiSTA.h header file.